# why a KO property gets split?

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following KO property:

```
this.propertyView = ko.pureComputed(function () {
    if (!$.isEmptyObject(this.properties())) {
        return this.properties().map(function (prop) {
            var singleProp = '';
            for (var p in prop) {
                if (prop[p]) {
                    singleProp += prop[p] + ', ';
                }
            }
            return singleProp.slice(0, -2);
        });
    }
    else return "TBD";
}, this);
```

And the HTML:

```
<span>PROPERTY</span>
<div data-bind="foreach: propertyView">
  <span data-bind="text: $data" class="fnt-normal"></span>
</div>
```

The issue is: if the object is not empty it's working fine but if **it is** empty it splits the "TBD"- each letter in a new line.
For example: if it's not empty it looks like that:

> test, 23 st, NY

If it is empty, i'm getting the "TBD" this way:

> T
>
> B
>
> D

Comment: Try returning ["TBD"] instead of "TBD". A string can be converted to an array of characters, so specify an array that contains a single string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try returning `["TBD"]` instead of `"TBD"`. A string can be converted to an array of characters, so specify an array that contains a single string

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're expecting to have an array returned from the function - this is what `.map` is giving you.  When you return a single string, knockout is iterating over each character with the `foreach`:

```
data-bind="foreach: propertyView"
```

You just need to wrap your default return in an array:

```
else return ["TBD"];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for your explanation, now I understand it. Sorry that I can't accept it as an answer, @DavidThomas answered it before...